# Teradata error - importing timestamp column with null values

Tags: teradata-sql-assistant

I have a timestamp column in a delimter file in the format '12/04/2018 15:38:42' and I am trying to import this file thro Teradata SQL assistant. I have defined the target table with this column as
SYSTEM_DT     Timestamp(0) FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYYBHH:MI:SS'
I am using the below statement to import, its loading fine until it detects a null value on the file for this column. I am getting 'Invalid timestamp' error.

```
INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE
VALUES (CAST(? AS TIMESTAMP(0) FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYYBHH:MI:SS'),?,?,?)
```

So I tried below, nothing worked - 
1. `CAST(COALESCE(? , '01/01/1900 00:00:00') AS TIMESTAMP(0) FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYYBHH:MI:SS')`
2. `COALESCE(CAST(? AS TIMESTAMP(0) FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYYBHH:MI:SS'), CAST('01/01/1900 00:00:00' AS TIMESTAMP(0) FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYYBHH:MI:SS'))`

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Assistant expects `NULL` to be represented by whatever string value you have specified in *Tools* / *Options* / *Data Format* as "Display this string for Null data values".

For example, if `NULL` is indicated by an empty string in your input dataset, delete all the characters from that option setting to have SQL Assistant send NULL to the database.

Alternatively you could use a `CASE` or `NULLIF` statement inside the CAST to have the database convert an empty string to `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working after I changed the options in Sql assistant.